# How to find the version number of Django-CMS

Tags: django-cms

I'm adding a new site to a server which already has Django & Django-CMS installed.  How can I detect the version number of the installed Django-CMS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from cms import __version__
print __version__
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on Python 3.3.4

```
    from cms import __version__
    print (__version__)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just do

```
python manage.py version
```

if you are using Linux it will be

```
./manage.py version
```

Comment: Works great for *Django*, but this (very, very old question) was about *Django CMS*. =)